# Issue with Picture Library Slideshow Web Part after export/import of site collection (SP2010)

Tags: sharepoint

I recently exported/imported an SP2010 site collection from Dev to Prod. The site collection had about 90 sites, which were all driven from a site template. Once the export/import had taken place, I created an additional 15 sites (in Prod), using the original site template that was created in the Dev environment. Everything seemed to be working just fine, but I found an issue with the Picture Library Slideshow Web Parts (PLSWP) on all the sites that were created in Prod. Basically, I have a Picture Library, and any pictures added to this library show up in the PLSWP. The original 80 site's PLSWP works fine, but the new 15 sites will not show the pictures through the PLSWP (the viewer just shows up blank). Here is the difference in the html output of the picture viewer:

```
**PLSWP from Dev:**
<a target="_blank" href="http://forefronttest/realestate/RE/West/HOU/3560/Project%20Pictures/test.jpg" id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_m_g_28b22a62_6d84_4176_bd3f_7240043d7b09_link">
 <img width="212" height="195" style="border: 0px none ; vertical-align: middle;" id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_m_g_28b22a62_6d84_4176_bd3f_7240043d7b09_curr" src="http://forefronttest/realestate/RE/West/HOU/3560/Project%20Pictures/_w/test_jpg.jpg" alt="">
</a>

**PLSWP from Prod:**
<a target="_blank" href="http://forefronttest/realestate/RE/West/DEN/2955/Project%20Pictures/test.jpg" id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_m_g_28b22a62_6d84_4176_bd3f_7240043d7b09_link">
 <img width="0" height="0" style="border: 0px none ; vertical-align: middle;" id="MSOPictureLibrarySlideshowWebPart_ctl00_m_g_28b22a62_6d84_4176_bd3f_7240043d7b09_curr" src="/_layouts/images/icjpg.gif" alt="">
</a>
```

You can notice from the above markup, that the PLSWP html from Prod is not correct. The src attribute on the  is /_layouts/images/icjpg.gif and the width and height attributes are 0. I have no idea why this is happening. I thought about using JQuery on the fly when the page loads to replace the src attribute with the href attribute of the  tag - but, I would like to stay away from this.

I know that the PLSWP is what is causing the problem, because I have tried pointing it to a different picture library - no luck. Also, I have tried deleting the PLSWP and re-adding a new one, but I have the same problem.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having to just delete the Picture Library and re-create it.